# Modal error in ui kit

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I want to use modal in my page.but when i call it browser console errors modal 
is not defined
included files to index file:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dist/semantic.min.css">
  <script src="dist/components/modal.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/components/modal.css">
  <script src="dist/components/modal.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/components/modal.min.css">
  <script src="dist/components/modal.min.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

and this is my code for calling modal:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     alert("Document Was ready");
     $('#sign').click(function(){
       $('.modal').modal('show');
     });
  });
```

This is error:`TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function`
and this is link of modal in semantic-ui:http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html
I use first modal ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move:

```
<script src="dist/components/modal.min.js"></script>
```

after:

```
<script src="./dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
```

because now you are trying to execute `$().modal` before Semantic have been loaded. Also, you are loading it twice and also a minified version; I assume you need only the minified version.

Your code should look like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./dist/semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/components/modal.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/components/modal.min.css">
<script src="./dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/components/modal.min.js"></script>
```

And it's good practice to load CSS files before scripts.